# Infragistics web currency edit round off issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, infragistics

in Infragistis web currency edit if max value is greater than 16 digits while focus out . it shows wrong round off value.

how to avoid this or how to remove the round off option for the web currency edit.

please see the below code

```
<igtxt:WebCurrencyEdit ID="txtWebCurrencyEdit" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"
DataMode="Decimal" MaxValue="99999999999999999999" MaxLength="20"
```

if i enter the value greater than 16 digits the its round off to wrong value also in i give 20 nine then round off to a number with 21 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `JavaScript` limitation on the client-side. In `JavaScript` the largest number is `9007199254740990`.

[JavaScript Number Type](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)